# Optimization problem in economics in Starcraft 2

Tags: optimization, game-theory

Let's say I'm playing a computer game like Starcraft 2 for one of the fraction, for example as Terrans. Each unit in this fraction has multiple parameters like build cost(minerals and gas), build time, attack values, armor values. For SC2 Terrans they all are listed [here](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Terran_Unit_Statistics_(Wings_of_Liberty_and_Heart_of_the_Swarm)).

This kind of games are very complex and the economics have a lot of dimensions, that's why I blend out for now all other questions (among other, decisions of other rational players) and limit the problem space only to: what is the best build order for Marines and Marauders (in regards to the build costs and build times) to gain best attack/armor values? But not from perspective of a "gamer" but more a mathematician who has only that table above.

If this question is still "to open" how to limit it further? What kind of mathematics instruments are needed to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: "best in regard to the build costs and build times to gain best attack/armor values" isn't well-defined. If there are several objectives (cost, time, attack and armour), you basically have two options to form a well-defined problem: You can either combine them into a single objective function that you want to optimize (for instance the product of attack and armour divided by the product of cost and time), or you can ask for the [pareto-optimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) solutions, i.e. the solutions that are such that no other solution is better with respect to all four.

Comment: In a good game, there will be many pareto-optimal solutions, because a game is boring if there's one way to do things that's better in all respects than other ways of doing things – it's precisely the fact that some approaches are better in some ways and others in others that makes a game interesting. If you want to boil this down to a mathematical optimization, you need to define a single quantity that you want to optimize.

Comment: Ok, but thats exactly what I tried to do with the attack/armor constraint, but then I can also live only with attack. I want understand the principe and the simplest use case here is enough.

Comment: Introducing constraints is yet another way to formulate a well-defined optimization problem. For instance, you could ask for the strategy that minimizes the product of time and cost under the constraint that attack and armour have certain values. But you didn't introduce any constraints – you just said "to gain best attack/armor values" and didn't specify how this is to be combined with the objective of minimizing cost and time. We can't define "the simplest use case" for you; that's not math. If you tell us what you want to optimize, we can tell you how to optimize it.